In array of objects with similar division, check the new record and previous record and aggregate the response in dataweave
Input:
[
  {
    "employeeId": 100,
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Chen",
    "division": "2024-DOA09-1111",
    "email": "john.chen@xxxx.com",
    "freshHire": false,
    "position": "M"
  },
  {
    "employeeId": 101,
    "firstName": "Ameya",
    "lastName": "Job",
    "division": "2024-DOA09-1111",
    "email": "ameya.job@xxx.com",
    "freshHire": false,
    "position": "M"
  },
  {
    "employeeId": 102,
    "firstName": "Pat",
    "lastName": "Fay",
    "division": "2024-DOA09-1111",
    "email": "pat.fey@xxx.com",
    "freshHire": false,
    "position": "M"
  }
]

dataweave code:
%dw 2.0
fun combine(val,old, new) = (if(if(val) true else (if((new.position == 'C') and !(isEmpty(new.employeeId)) ) true else false)) true else (if((old.position == 'D') and !(isEmpty(old.employeeId)) ) true else false))
output application/json
---
(payload map ((item, index) -> if(sizeOf(payload) == 2) (combine(payload[index].freshHire,payload[index], payload[index+1])) else (combine((combine(payload[index].freshHire,payload[index], payload[index+1])), payload[index+1], payload[index+2]))))[0]

expected output:
false
Condition for the dataweave is as follows.
Boolean value = if(oldfreshHire == true) true else (if((newPosition == "M") and !isEmpty(newemployeeId)) true else false)
value1= if(value == true) true else (if((oldPosition == "M") and !isEmpty(oldemployeeId)) true else false)

oldPosition=Position value in index 0, newPosition=Position value in index 1, this continue for all indexes next oldPosition will be the response of 1st and 2nd record and newPosition will be 3rd record and so on.. old and new prefix is same for all fields mentioned.
Here value variable is first determined and then that value is again used for value1 evaluation. value1 variable will be the final output which is expected.
Here Input has 3 records so based on the condition, 1st and 2nd record with employeeId 100 and 101 are passed to the condition as old and new respectively. oldfreshHire=false from 1st record, newPosition=M and newemployeeId=101 from 2nd record, so value=false. then oldPosition=M and oldemployeeId=100 so value1=false.
then we will consider previous result as old and 3rd record as new so oldfreshHire=false(value1 result), newPosition=M and newemployeeId=102 from 3rd record so value=false as per condition. then oldPosition=M and oldemployeeId=101 from 2nd record so it will consider (index-1) as old for position and employeeId and value1=false as final result.
I am getting the required output for the given input but if there are more then this might not work. also I wanted to check if this code is correct or we can update it to alternate one. Please let me know if this can be updated.

You shared "Condition for the dataweave" that has two variables. Which one is the result? Please explain in words the logic for the condition. It is not clear what is the check.

both should be applied first value is evaluated and then that value is considered for value1 where value1 will be the final output.

If you are only looking for the first element of the array ("expected output: false"), why bother to apply the same logic to all items?

I don't fully understand the logic but what the script is doing is applying the combine() function to each element and the next one. That can also be done using the reduce() built-in function.
Also combine() is overcomplicated. If you are going to return true or false depending on a condition just return the condition. It doesn't needs a separate argument if the value is also part of another argument.
This seems to return the same result, but as I said it is not fully clear what is intended.
%dw 2.0
output application/json  

fun combine(val, old, new) =
    if ((val) or        
            ((new.position == 'C') and !(isEmpty(new.employeeId))))
        true
    else ((old.position == 'D') and !(isEmpty(old.employeeId)))
---
(payload reduce ((item, accumulator={old:{}, previous:null }) 
    -> {old: item, previous: combine(accumulator.previous default item.freshHire, accumulator.old, item)})).previous

Output:
false


expected result is just false and not an array, where all the records are passed to combine() function. I was not able to do it in other way so implemented like that. for now there are 3 records so first and second is considered as old and new respectively and then result of first and second(which is false) will be old and third record as new. If there are 4 records then it should consider result of (first+second+third) as old and fourth as new and so on.

I modified the answer to align with your comment. Instead of accumulating an array of booleans I preserved the previous value to use with the next one. Since I don't have other inputs to test please verify if the result is correct.

Thank you @aled, I will check with other inputs.
